# Google actions not showing cards in test

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've created a simple helper in api.ai to tell and added a few intents with responses that link to google actions. When I link my agent to a google project and test it with those intents i get the following errors:

```
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: the first element must be a 'simple_response' or a 'structured_response'.
```

and

```
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[0].basic_card.image: 'accessibility_text' is required.
```

these are both classified as Malformed Response Errors, but I don't really understand seeing as I didn't write any code, simply just used used the UI for api.ai and google projects

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Actions on Google responses still require a text response to be displayed and/or spoken in addition to the card responses. So in the Actions on Google section of the response, you must either set "Use response from the DEFAULT tab as the first response" on:

[image]

or you must add a Simple Response:

[image]

When you enter a Basic Card, if you enter an Image URL, you must also enter the Image Accessibility Text:

[image]